# Linux error message: permission denied after giving all of the permissions

Tags: shell, sqlplus

When I run command

`./load_test_triples.sh TMODEL/Map.ttl TMODEL Y >> load_semantic.log`

I get following message:

```
./load_test_triples.sh: line 72: =: Permission denied
```

it doesn't like something in my script, because if I take out the code starting at line 54 and after, it works just fine:

```
 12 MODEL=$2
 13 REPLACE=$3
 .
 .
 54 get_count () {
 55     sqlplus -s user/pass <<!
 56     set heading off
 57     set feedback off
 58     set pages 0
 59     select PRNCT_CHANGE
 60     FROM COUNT_STATISTICS
 61     WHERE model = '$MODEL'
 62     AND NEW_DATE = (SELECT MAX(NEW_DATE)
 63                     FROM COUNT_STATISTICS
 64                     WHERE MODEL = '$MODEL');
 65 !
 66 }
 67
 68 count=$(get_count $1)
 69
 70 echo $count   #echoes right number
 71
 72 if [ $count >= 0 ]; then
 73     echo "is greater than or equal zero"
 74 else
 75     echo "is less to zero"
 76 fi
```

Anyone knows what could be a problem?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to do in shell script what should properly be done in an actual programming language. Shell script is dangerous; it's easy to get the impression that it is a powerful and expressive language, and then you start trying to do anything in it, and the next thing you know you're gnawing your leg off at the knee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `test` command, `>=` is interpreted as an output redirection to a file called `=`. There is no `>=` operator in shell, but you want to use the operator `-ge` for integer comparision anyway:

```
if [ "${count:-0}" -ge 0 ]; then
```

Comment: if I change to that I get:            ./load_test_triples.sh: line 72: [: -ge: unary operator expected

Comment: if I add double quotes around variable count I get: ./load_test_triples.sh: line 72: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: That sounds like `count` is set to the empty string. It would be good to fix `get_count`, but I can provide a work-around. My answer assumes that the empty string should be treated as 0.

Comment: well, we know that if we echo count it gives us the right value. So I separated the logic: 
if [ $count > 0 ] && [ $count = 0 ]; then
    echo "is greater than or equal to zero"
else
    echo "is less then zero"
fi
 But it is still saying "is less then zero" even though the value it echoes is 10 for examples

Comment: Awesome!  if [ "${count:-0}" -ge 0 ]; then   worked. what's the logic behind the :- ?

Comment: what if the count is null? how can I check for null value? I would like to add another elseif if is negative and else for everything else. How do I do that?